# How to populate store in vuex before component renders

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am using vuex to save a tree structure in the state property.

The data is fetched with an ajax call.

The problem is that the page manages to render before the variable I have in the state property manages to populate.

i.e

```
// sth.ts file
state: {
    map: {}
},
...
actions: {
    getData({ commit }){
        axios.get(...).then(... populate map ...).catch(...)
    }
}


// sthelse.vue file
<template>
<div>
<h1>Tree structure</h1>
<ul >
    <item v-for="child in map[root]"
             :key="child.id"
             :name="child.name"
             :children="child.Children">
    </item>
</ul>
</div>
</template>
```

I have googled but I haven't found something that works.
Has anybody dealt with a similar problem?

Is there a way it can be done?

Comment: Why do you have actions in .vue file, syntax of action is also not correct. `actions` is an object that contains methods

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I don't, that is a typo. Fixed!

Comment: where is he action name , how and where are you dispatching the action?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna. I have updated the actions. The action is dispatched from within sthelse.vue file.

Comment: show the relevant part of script in sthelse.vue file like data , methods if you are dispatching the action in method or else created r mounted hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a reference to the loaded map keys inside the vuex state like:

```
state: {
    map: {},
    keysLoaded: []
}
```

Then inside the mutation that handle the data push the key to `keysLoaded`, the in your component you can use a computed property like:

```
showTree () {
    return this.$store.state.keysLoaded.includes(this.root)
}
```

render the ul only if showTree its true:

```
<ul v-if="showTree">
```